# Azure Databricks processing files differently based on the confuguration

Tags: azure-databricks

We've an application which processes huge file(excel) and calculate data from that file based on different conditions(written/coded in scala notebook).

The issue which we're facing is the inconsistency of results produced by the same file for different time and/or different configuration for Azure Databricks Compute.

We've already double check our scala notebook code and which doesn't has any bug, it might be something from configuration end(not sure).

Below is the current configuration of my dev compute
[image]

Comment: what kind of inconsistency do you observe?

Comment: ex. A file which we're taking data from needs to calculate and output of 28K rows, but it different as I explained above